# Let G be a group with a normal series, such that each quotient $G/G_{i}$ is abelian for $i=\{1...n-1\}$. Prove that $G^{(i)} \le G_i $ for all $i$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

This is the task I'm trying to solve:

[image]

I'm confused about what $G_i/G_{i+1}$ being abelian implies here. I assume the notation $G^{(i)}$ just means G multiplied with itself i times. But still, nothing comes to mind as to how the use the information im given here.

Comment: No, it is the $i$th derived subgroup. Your guess isn’t a subgroup in general.

Comment: Derived subgroup, as in the commutator of $G_i$?

Comment: And the result is easy if you know that $G/H$ abelian $\implies G'\le H$.

Comment: The derived subgroup is defined as the smallest normal subgroup s.t. the quotient is abelian. Since $G_i / G_{i+1}$ is abelian, then the commutator must be inside $G_{i}$, which gives us the answer. Correct?

Comment: No, the $i$th derived subgroup is the commutator of the $i-1$th derived subgroup, the first derived subgroup is the commutator. The fact that $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is abelian means that the commutator of $G_i$ is contained in $G_{i+1}$ but you have to work a little harder to get the $i$th derived subgroup of $G$ in there, it depends on the previous quotients being abelian too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main fact you should notice is that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $G/H$ is abelian iff $G^{(1)}\subseteq H$

We start with $G$: Note that since $G/G_{1}$ is abelian, we have $G^{(1)}\subseteq G_{1}$. Now we have $G^{(1)}G_{2}<G_{1}$, and by the second isomorphism theorem, we have $G^{(1)}/(G^{(1)}\cap G_2) \cong (G^{(1)}G_2)/G_2 \subseteq G_1/G_2$.

Since $G_1/G_2$ is abelian, we have $G^{(1)}/(G^{(1)}\cap G_2)$ is abelian. Thus, $G^{(2)}\subseteq (G^{(1)}\cap G_2) \subseteq G_2$.

The resulst follows from repeating the steps.

Answer (score 1):

We have, by assumption, since the quotients are all abelian, that $G_i'\le G_{i+1}$.

But, then $G^1\le G_1\implies G^2\le G_1'\le G_2 \implies \dots\implies G^{n-1}\le G_{n-1} $.